Why does psycopg error our when running an executemany
I am using psycopg to create local copies of some cloud tables and I'm running into some issues. I have the following code:
type_to_postgres = {"<class 'int'>": 'integer',
                            "<class 'str'>": 'text',
                            "<class 'float'>": 'float',
                            "<class 'bool'>": 'bool',
                            "<class 'datetime.datetime'>": 'timestamp',
                            "<class 'datetime.date'>": 'date',
                            "<class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>": 'timestamp',
                            "<class 'NoneType'>": 'text'}
column_definitions = ''
for i in range(len(value_list[0])):
    column_definitions += keys[i] + ' ' + type_to_postgres.get(str(type(value_list[0][i])), 'text') + ', '
    column_definitions = column_definitions[:-2]
    try:
        cur.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tebra." + table_name.lower())
        cur.execute("CREATE TABLE tebra." + table_name.lower() + " (" + column_definitions + ");")
        cur.executemany("INSERT INTO tebra." + table_name.lower() + " VALUES (" + ", ".join(["%s"] * len(keys)) + ")", value_list)
        conn.commit()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e, table_name)

And it works fine for all of my tables except for one. It fails and prints the following error:
error ignored terminating <psycopg.Pipeline [ACTIVE, pipeline=ON] (host=10.1.10.77 database=postgres) at 0x258806e3c50>: flushing failed: No error (0x00000000/0)
SSL SYSCALL error: No error (0x00000000/0)
SSL SYSCALL error: No error (0x00000000/0)
error ignored exiting <psycopg.Pipeline [ACTIVE, pipeline=ON] (host=10.1.10.77 database=postgres) at 0x258806e3c50>: No error (0x00000000/0)
SSL SYSCALL error: No error (0x00000000/0)
SSL SYSCALL error: No error (0x00000000/0)
cannot exit pipeline mode while busy

I haven't been able to find any information on this online. I can get the table to correctly insert by doing the executes with individual inserts, but this is significantly slower. I thought it might be the table size, but this table is only 4.2M, while my largest table is 241M and works fine. It does have some fields that contain a large amount of text, so I don't know if that plays into the issue.
My Postgres version (installed with Ubuntu):
PostgreSQL 14.12 (Ubuntu 14.12-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0, 64-bit
My psycopg version:
3.1.18
Edit:
Per Adrian's advice I upgraded my psycopg version to 3.2.1 and I am still getting a similar error, though slightly different. Here it is:
error ignored terminating <psycopg.Pipeline [BAD] at 0x2292b42be60>: the connection is lost
sending prepared query failed: SSL SYSCALL error: EOF detected

After a quick search I didn't see anything relevant for this error either.
Edit 2:
Here is what the create table execute returns:
<psycopg.Cursor [COMMAND_OK] [INTRANS] (host=10.1.10.77 database=postgres) at 0x21584b8e150>

And here is the log message after failing the insert:
2024-08-08 21:26:40.204 UTC [28654] postgres@postgres LOG:  incomplete message from client

And my full create table statement:
CREATE TABLE tebra.pm_clearinghouseresponse (
    customerid integer,
    clearinghouseresponseid integer,
    clearinghouseresponsereporttypeid integer,
    clearinghouseresponsereporttypename text,
    clearinghouseresponsesourcetypeid integer,
    clearinghouseresponsesourcetypename text,
    denied float,
    filecontents text,
    filename text,
    filereceivedate timestamp,
    itemcount integer,
    paymentid float,
    practiceguid text,
    processedflag bool,
    rejected integer,
    responsetype integer,
    clearinghouseresponsetypename text,
    reviewedflag bool,
    sourceaddress text,
    sourcename text,
    title text,
    totalamount text
);


To your question add 1) Exact Postgres version. 2) Where you got Postgres from or where you are running it(for cloud versions). 3) Exact psycopg(3) version.

Here is the output of select version():
PostgreSQL 14.12 (Ubuntu 14.12-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0, 64-bit
I downloaded it with the ubuntu installation, and my psycopg version is 3.1.18. Thank you!

Add the information to the question text so others do not have to walk through the comments to get essential information.

psycopg(3) is at 3.2.1, I would suggest upgrading to that and testing.

To the question text add 1) The result of "CREATE TABLE tebra." .... 2) Any relevant information from the Postgres log when the INSERT is done. As a suggestion you might want to look at COPY as an alternate method to add the data, it would be quicker.

Ok I've added that info, and I'll take a look at the copy statement and see if I can make that work. Thanks!


Actually I was looking for the complete CREATE TABLE ... statement as sent to the database. 2) I would also suggest you file an issue here psycopg Issues.


Oh gotcha, I added the full statement above. I'll take a look at creating an issue over there as well, thanks for the link!

And as a side note: you should beusing Python f-strings instead of concatenating strings with "+" - it they are much easier to type and to read and less error prone.

@jsbueno As a side not to the side note, you should not use f strings but use instead the psycopg module sql. This is the safe way to build dynamic SQL.

SQL connectors bindings will are ok, and the correct thing to do for the data arguments (whatever goes in as values), but they don't interpolate table names (let alone fragments of table names) into the statements.

Good point on both of those, I'll get it updated. I did end up converting the code to use copy as Adrian suggested and the code runs without errors and has comparable speeds, so I'll be going with that approach.

@AlexChilds I think the problem is with large SQL statements. I have a similar problem and I don't know how to fix it yet... but my query is larger than yours...
